# Changing dcast to show multiple columns

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following situation. Consider the following df:

```
mymatrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 0, nrow = 7, ncol = 4))
colnames(mymatrix) <- c("Patient", "marker", "Number", "Visit")

mymatrix[,1] <- c("B1","B1","C1","C1","D1","D1","D1")
mymatrix[,2] <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
mymatrix[,3] <- c(1,0,0,15,1,2,13)
mymatrix[,4] <- c("baseline","followup","baseline","followup","baseline","followup","followup")

> mymatrix
  Patient marker Number    Visit
1      B1      A      1 baseline
2      B1      A      0 followup
3      C1      A      0 baseline
4      C1      A     15 followup
5      D1      A      1 baseline
6      D1      A      2 followup
7      D1      A     13 followup
```

If I do dcast on the first 6 rows I get:

```
> dcast(mymatrix[1:6,], Patient +marker~Visit, value.var = "Number")
  Patient marker baseline followup
1      B1      A        1        0
2      C1      A        0       15
3      D1      A        1        2
```

If I do dcast on all the rows I get:

```
> dcast(mymatrix, Patient +marker~Visit, value.var = "Number")
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  Patient marker baseline followup
1      B1      A        1        1
2      C1      A        1        1
3      D1      A        1        2
```

Is there a way instead of defaulting to length it would add a second followup column? So the data would show as follows:

```
  Patient marker baseline followup.1 followup.2
1      B1      A        1        0     NA
2      C1      A        0        15     NA
3      D1      A        1        2     13
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you asking for. You desired output contains two different functions. All the columns until `followup.2` are using `length`, while `followup.2` is the second `followup` value in each group? That doesn't make any sense to me. Do you mean that you want to add `followup.2` to your first output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you asking, because it seems like you want to combine two different functions in `dcast` at the same time. It seems to me that you want to improve your first output instead of the second. If so, a simple solution would be just to add an automatic index to the values in the `Visit` column and then `dcast`. Here's a simple approach using the `data.table` package (thought the output is not exactly what you want because I've also added an index to `baseline`, but it can get you started)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mymatrix)[, Visit := paste(Visit, seq_len(.N), sep = "."), list(Patient, Visit)]
dcast.data.table(mymatrix, Patient + marker ~ Visit, value.var = "Number")

#    Patient marker baseline.1 followup.1 followup.2
# 1:      B1      A          1          0         NA
# 2:      C1      A          0         15         NA
# 3:      D1      A          1          2         13
```

Comment: you're right, I wanted it to append to my second solution. Typo -- this works :-).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `base R`

```
d1 <- transform(mymatrix, Visit=paste0(Visit,ave(seq_along(Number),
                                      Patient, Visit, FUN=seq_along)) )

reshape(d1, idvar=c('Patient', 'marker'), timevar='Visit', direction='wide')
#   Patient marker Number.baseline1 Number.followup1 Number.followup2
#1      B1      A                1                0               NA
#3      C1      A                0               15               NA
#5      D1      A                1                2               13
```

Or `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mymatrix %>%
        group_by(Patient, Visit) %>% 
        mutate(indx=row_number()) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        unite(Visit1, Visit, indx) %>% 
        spread(Visit1, Number)
#   Patient marker baseline_1 followup_1 followup_2
#1      B1      A          1          0         NA
#2      C1      A          0         15         NA
#3      D1      A          1          2         13
```